# How can i use vuex's actions in vue-router's beforeEach

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, vuex

I want to check if the data is in store before every router change, if the data is not in the vuex, i want to use vuex's actions to get the data from server. so how can i user actions in  beforeEach.

i use the vue2.0

Answer (score 4):

can use router.app.$store.dispatch('actionName')

Comment: Works if you have imported the store as [M U](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1766444/m-u) stated.

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do is `import store from '/vuex` and actions
Depends how you built your actions you can be pushed to pass store instance to action.
Other than that - it is straight forward.